# How to convert features of layer from POLYGON to MULTIPOLYGON?

Tags: qgis, polygon, geometry

How can I convert features of a layer from POLYGON to MULTIPOLYGON?
I know how to do that using the postgis function [ST_Multi](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/ST_Multi.html) but how could I do to same thing for a layer in QGIS?

Comment: Seems to be a comment please expand on what your are asking

Answer (score 9):

If you want to do it based on a field, you can do this in QGIS from the menu: `Vector --> Geometry Tools --> Collect Geometries` (requires at least two poylgons to share an attribute that you specify).

There is a more direct equivalent to ST_Multi in OGR.  I didn't find a way to access this specific OGR functionality through QGIS, but that could be done using GDAL/OGR like this `ogr2ogr -nlt MULTIPOLYGON multipolygon_output.shp polygon_input.shp` More details on -nlt switch are available on the [ogr2ogr page](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html).

Comment: I mamanged to do it with GDAL/OGR as you said, thanks. Let's see if someone can find a solution to this directly in QGIS.

Comment: In QGIS 3 the tool is now called "Collect geometries"

Answer (score 0):

While still waiting for the simple QGIS solution you can have a look at how it goes with OpenJUMP through the right-click menu:

[image]